# Removing strange borders around HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to learning very basic HTML. I can't figure out how to remove the grey lines around my buttons. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[image: Here's a screenshot of the grey boxes]

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>social follow bar</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#00FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (social follow bar.psd) -->
        <table id="Table_01" width="250" height="40" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/wherefoodtakesus/pins/">
                        <img src="https://wherefoodtakesus.com/wp-content/uploads/Home-Page/Buttons/Social-Sharing-Buttons/Pinterest_button.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="Pinterest-Follow_button"></a></td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/wherefoodtakesusblog/">
                        <img src="https://wherefoodtakesus.com/wp-content/uploads/Home-Page/Buttons/Social-Sharing-Buttons/Instagram_button.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="Instagram-Follow_button"></a></td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <a href="https://wherefoodtakesus.com/feed/">
                        <img src="https://wherefoodtakesus.com/wp-content/uploads/Home-Page/Buttons/Social-Sharing-Buttons/RSS_button.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="RSS-Follow_button"></a></td>
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <a href="https://mix.com/wherefoodtakesus">
                        <img src="https://wherefoodtakesus.com/wp-content/uploads/Home-Page/Buttons/Social-Sharing-Buttons/Mix_button.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="Mix-Follow_button"></a></td>
                
                <td rowspan="2">
                    <a href="mailto:wherefoodtakesus@gmail.com">
                        <img src="https://wherefoodtakesus.com/wp-content/uploads/Home-Page/Buttons/Social-Sharing-Buttons/Email_button.png" width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="Email_button"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No "grey lines" appear at the rendered HTML at stacksnippets

Comment: Right click on those boxes to see them in the browser Inspector. That should tell you where the style is defined (it isn't in the code you've shared). Also, styling with HTML attributes like `bgcolor` is a technique from 20th century that's already obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like grey boxes are coming from one of your imported css files. Please try to change your `<td rowspan="2">` to `<td rowspan="2" style="border:0;">`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the lines are from some imported css file. Try adding "border:0;" to the *td* elements:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="border:0;">
```